# Laravel foreach loop database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, loops, foreach

I'm kinda new to programming in general. I'm trying to loop through a table. There is a connection to the DB already. It's giving me - "Object of class Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection could not be converted to string"

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    
    function list(){  
    $serve = DB::table('sport'); 
    foreach($serve as $val){
        return strval($val);
    } 
    }

    
}
```

That's my code so far. How can I fix that issue?

Thanks!

Comment: fyi, `return` in a loop will exit the loop after returning the first element

Comment: Do you need just the first entry?

Comment: _I'm kinda new to programming in general_ Then directly starting with a framework is a bad idea!

Comment: I switched to `echo strval($val);` but still, it cannot be converted to string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for iterating throgh table rows , you need to make your objects iterable ,
when you do :

```
 $serves = DB::table('sport');
```

you are not actually make it iterable ;
use get() method to make it terable:

```
 $serves = DB::table('sport')->get();
```

Now you can iterate over it .

```
foreach($serves as $serve){
   //$serve->field; 
}
```

notice that each $serve item is a model of Sport model
and now you can access the fields of sport table from  this method

for eample if you have the fields in you sports table :

1. id
2. sport_name
3. created_at
4. updated_at

you can access them like this :

```
foreach($serves as $serve){
   echo $serve->id;
   echo $serve->sport_name;
}
```

finally please try to give better naming
and change $serves to $sports
and $serve to $sport to enhance  code readibility.

Comment: Could you also do `foreach (DB::table(..)->get() as $val)`?

Comment: yes you can 
Also notice that you can not use return statement in  foreach loop 
and also by this  $serve variable in your foreach statement you will access the model object  I will update the answer .

Comment: But notice doing  DB::table(..)->get()  for each iteration is not a good practice because
it is a heavy task and by this way it will be repeated  each time for iteration and we don't want it , so it is good to do it outside the iteration.

Comment: Why would that be evaluated for each iteration? It should be evaluated once at the start of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

To loop in a table you can use:

```
DB::table('sports')->orderBy('id')->chunk(100, function ($sports) {
    foreach ($sports as $sport) {
        //your code
    }
});
```

Comment: It's nice that this has pagination.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the sport table data first and then loop over on it:

```
$sports = DB::table('sport')->get();

foreach($sports as $sport){
  // $sport->table_field; do something here
}
```

Comment: If I put it above the function it's giving me an error for an unexpected variable name

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    
    function list(){  
       $serve = DB::table('sport')->get(); 
          foreach($serve as $val){
           // code
          } 
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what the problem was/how your code solves that instead of just dumping code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how it looks now and it returns the values in the localhost.

```
function list(){  
    foreach(DB::table('sport')->get() as $val){
        print_r($val);
    } 
    }
```